How to literally translate this: 不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦?
2002年元旦，战胜疾病的他决定把自己创办的网站公开，让更多喜欢中文的人在学习汉字时，不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 21. I need your help for the literal translation of this: 不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。
不再(?)像(?)他(he)最初(beginning)那样(?)学得(learning)那么(?)痛苦(suffering)
As you can see, I cannot understand the adverbs.
不再 I think means no more, but I don't understand what it modifies.
像 I think means like but I don't know what it refers to
那样 means so, that, like that?
那么 means so and it is about the suffering? Something like so suffering or much suffering?

不再(never again)像(be like)他(him)最初(at the very beginning)那样(that kind)学得(learning)那么(that)痛苦(suffer)

never again be in that kind like him that suffered at the very beginning of learning.


学中文还得是靠R哥 翻译信达雅

不再: no longer, no more
像他: like him
最初: in the beginning
学得那么痛苦: study de very arduous
2002年元旦，
On New Year's Day 2002,
战胜疾病的他决定把自己创办的网站公开，
having overcome his illness, he decided to make public the website he had created,
让更多喜欢中文的人在学习汉字时，
to allow more people who like Chinese, when they are studying,
不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。
to no longer be like him when he started: studying was very arduous.

不再 = no longer
像[他最初]那样 = like that way [he was at the beginning]
学(得)那么 = studying (to the degree of) that
痛苦 = painfully (adv - modifies 学)

(他)不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。

(He) no longer studying that painfully like the way he was at the beginning

…… so that more of those who are fond of Chinese language won't suffer as much as he did as a fresh learner while learning Chinese.
…… 让更多喜欢中文的人在学习汉字时，不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。
This is a bit tricky and roundabout though.

I'd translate this to:

2002年元旦，战胜疾病的他决定把自己创办的网站公开，让更多喜欢中文的人在学习汉字时，不再像他最初那样学得那么痛苦。
New Year's Day 2002, after overcoming illness, he decided to launch his self-founded website, so even more Chinese-language enthusiasts, when studying Chinese, no longer have the study pains like those he had initially.

You're meant to be envisaging people struggling when studying Chinese, just like he was at the start.  But after launching his website, people can use it, and not have to suffer the same way he suffered.
It's quite challenging to directly translate this; it uses components and word orders that aren't used in English.

不再 I think means no more, but I don't understand what it modifies.

Yes that's correct.  The content after 不再 is no longer true (but it was true).  Specifically, 更多喜欢中文的人 no longer have to suffer the way he did (because of his website).

像 I think means like but I don't know what it refers to
那样 means so, that, like that?

Yes.  You might be better off not separating 像 + [sth.] + 那样 which is one of the many ways of saying "like [sth.]".  The 那样 implies how it is similar to [sth.], but in this example it's unspecific and just says "like that".  There's a variety of ways of expressing analogies like this (example sentences sourced from YouDao; my translations):

大人有时也会像小孩那样愚蠢行事。  (Adults are sometimes do things foolishly, like a child.)
像东京这样的城市正在扩展。  (Cities similar to Tokyo are developing.)
他像狐狸一样狡猾。  (He's as sly as a fox.)
我浑身颤抖、像一片叶子似的抖动。  (I was shaking all over, quivering like a leaf.)

So the 那样 doesn't really mean very much in itself and could easily be replaced by another word.  It's there to help the listener/reader interpret the sentence, rather than convey meaning.

那么 means so and it is about the suffering? Something like so suffering or much suffering?

The 那么 here grammatically functions the same as 很, but it's somewhat stronger.  You've probably encountered it many times before (and maybe even used it in phrases such as 老师说得那么快 or 我汉字写得那么慢).

……学得那么痛苦。  (...studied so hard.)

